# How to organize strings through a sort method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

This is a program that lets user input 6 random letters, and the program sorts these letters in order. Ex user inputs j, d, e, l, w, q and program outputs d, e, j, l, q, w.

Unfortunately the code freaks out and does not sort a thing. Note: I am using a GUI

Under public I created a class and an array to eventually house all inputted letters

```
class Abc {
        String letter;

        Abc (String _letter) {
           letter = _letter;
        }
    }

    ArrayList <Abc> alphabet = new ArrayList <Abc>(3); //note its 3, not 6 like in the example
```

After user types in a letter in a textField, they press the "addButton" which adds and saves the value in the array.

```
String letter = letterField.getText();

        //Store values in array 
        Abc a = new Abc(letter);
        alphabet.add(a);
```

Now for the actual 'sorting' part. Which takes place after user presses a "Play" button.

```
String[] abc = new String[3]; //LINE I FORGOT TO ADD

for (int k = 0; k < abc.length; k++) {
            abc[k] = letterField.getText();

             int x;
            for (int i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
                // Asume first value is x
                x = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < abc.length; j++) {
                    //find smallest value in array (random)
                    if (abc[j].compareToIgnoreCase(abc[x]) < 0) {
                        x = j;
                    }
                }
                if (x != i) {
                    //swap the values if not in correct order
                    final String temp = abc[i];
                    abc[i] = abc[x];
                    abc[x] = temp;
                }
                textArea.append(abc[i] + "\n");// Output correct order
            }
        }
```

I had originally used this code to sort integers, the only difference between that program and this program is the int/String and this one I am currently working on allows the user to input the letters and the program does not randomize them like it did with the integer program.

I had thought this would be enough code to do the trick and organize some letters, but apparently not.

For the actually problem, when I input the letters and add them to the array and press "play" the program freaks and a lovely error pops up...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "d"
```

Note: 'd' being the last letter I inputted for the last time I tested the program...all of five seconds ago.

Any hints or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Google `NumberFormatException`. And check for a line number.

Comment: your error is not in the code u show, and u are doing a for loop setting always the same value  `abc[k] = letterField.getText();` besides if u declared ur array with null values it would throw a nullPointerException ..

Answer (score 1):

A `NumberFormatException` is thrown when you attempt to parse some text into a number, but the text is not a number, such as in your example: `"d"`.

You mentioned that you had this code working with integers, then converted it to work with letters.  Most likely, you forgot to take out the code (which you haven't shown here) that parses the input into a number.  You should take out that code and accept the user's input as text as originally inputted.

Comment: I've double checked my code for that, but did not find anything. Though I did miss a line of code in this question that I added and commented next to it. I realize now that there is some 'disconnect' between the class/array I created to store info and the random array I forgot about...which just so happens to be the array in the sort part of the code. So, how should I fix that disconnect?

Comment: The exception should have come with a trace that contains the line number where the exception was thrown.  That line number will tell you where your code went wrong.

Comment: As a teach-yourself beginner in java...and coding in general I don't quite understand your most recent answer about the line telling me what I did wrong, considering not a single line in my entire program is underlined red (which then normally if I hovered over the line a explanation to why it was not working would pop-up) Is it impolite to ask you again to re-read my code to double check it over yourself? I've been reading my eyes out for the past 1 hour and 3 minutes to have gotten no where.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using parseInt() or something similar in the part of the code, where you get input from user. That method should be off now, as you no longer want to change input from String to any number.
By the way, just for information, class Arrays in java include some sorting methods. You can check those at this [site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)